# Do Windows 11 Recovery Drives contain the currently installed drivers?

Tags: drivers, windows-11, windows-installation, recovery-disk

I tried to reinstall Windows 11 using the installation media by following the steps on the [Create installation media for Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-installation-media-for-windows-99a58364-8c02-206f-aa6f-40c3b507420d) page. When I booted the USB, I found that it did not contain drivers for my touchpad or SSD, rendering it useless.

If I create a recovery drive following the step on the [Create a recovery drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246) page, will that drive include the basic drivers, for example, touchpad, SSD, wifi?

If not, what is the most simple way to get a Windows installation medium with the bare minimum drivers on it?

Comment: You don't need to, usually. Windows Update will usually install everything you need. Very rarely you actually need to download drivers from the website of whoever made the hardware. https://w365.dk/index.php/2022/03/19/how-to-add-drivers-to-windows-installation-iso-windows-10-11/

Comment: If you got your computer from a manufacturer such as Dell then they may provide a recovery image with all the drivers and software you require.

Comment: No; The “recovery drive” will not contain the drivers you want.  Is there a reason you don’t go to the OEM website for your laptop and download the drivers and install them? [Edit] your question instead of submitting temporary commentary

Comment: @Gantendo you still need to at least have the SSD drivers to get Windows installed in the first place, i.e., before you can use Windows Update...

Comment: @Ramhound the SSD has been completely erased and I am not sure if the OEM has complete images with Windows on them -- I will have to check.

Comment: @mallwright - I am suggesting you visit the OEM website to download the drivers.  OEM partitions are beyond worthless. I didn't mention the need for "OEM images".

Comment: @Ramhound how would I go about installing the drivers from the OEM website if I do not have a working Windows installation and cannot install Windows since the installation media does not provide the drivers for my SSD?

Comment: @mallwright - "does not provide the drivers for my SSD?" - You don't require drivers to install to a SSD.  If you are getting an error, and are unable to select the device, that means you have booted into Legacy Mode and are attempting to target a drive with 
a GPT schema, or likewise you are in UEFI mode and attempting to target a drive with an MBR schema.  You will have to use the keyboard or an external mouse to avoid the driver issue with the touchpad.

Answer (score 1):

> Do Windows 11 Recovery Drives contain the currently installed drivers?

If you have updated drivers (yourself or via Windows updates), then *no*, the recovery partition from the manufacturer setup does not contain the updates.

The recovery partition does contain the original drivers needed to update the system.

You can use the Recovery Partition (Backup and Recovery) and get back the the manufacturer setup. You do not need a USB key for this.

You can make your own setup from the Media Creation Link. That is different, and does not contain your drivers.   However, there is often a Driver Update step during this process and that will update drivers.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10

The second method normally provides newest Windows and will provide basic drivers. You might then need the manufacturer's Driver Update App to clean up.

If you cannot get the Microsoft tools to work, you will need to contact Dell Support and get a recovery USB for your model from them

Comment: The first method did not include SSD drivers so there is no way forward without "sideloading" them (which I would rather avoid), the second method took about 2 hours to create the "recovery drive" medium which I then booted and selected the full restore option which, after 3 hours of waiting, simply reported that an error had occurred, leaving me with a completely inoperable system -- thanks Microsoft!

Comment: If the Recovery Partition did not have SSD drivers that means the machine did not come with SSD.   If the second method did not work (ending in error), then you may need to update BIOS for the SSD.  I have used both methods I posted and the methods do work fine in the majority of cases.

Comment: I never mentioned a recovery partition because there isn't one. I think it was removed to make space for another OS. The recovery process I am talking about is described here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-a-recovery-drive-abb4691b-5324-6d4a-8766-73fab304c246

Comment: Instead of making a recovery drive to replace the deleted partition, use the Media Creation Link (https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10) to create an install ISO.  Start with that and one step in the process is to update drivers.  I mentioned this in my answer.  This may well work.

Comment: I have done that and cannot get to the update drivers step since I cannot get further than the "Where should Windows be installed" step (since the SSD drivers are not available).

Comment: You may need to get the Recovery USB from Dell and then start over in terms of installation.

Comment: You will need to give Dell your specific model to get the correct USB .  I made a note of this in my answer above